# Firestore .get() inside .map

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a two-step firebase firestore codes. The first step grabs all the users online, and the second check learning_language is equal. The first steps generates a map loop to traverse through all the online users. But the console.log at the end returns an empty array.

```
        db.collection(ns_status).where("state", "==", "online").onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
          var ns_match = snapshot.docs.map(function(userSnapshot) {
            db.collection(ns_profile).doc(userSnapshot.id).get().then(function(doc) {
              spoken_language = doc.data().spoken_language;
              if (learning_language == spoken_language) {
                return (userSnapshot.id);
              }
            })
          })
          console.log(ns_match);
        })
```

How do I grab the properly stored array at the end? I feel that it is an asynchronous problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would `filter()` be better suited here, rather than `map()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to acquire an array of `userSnaphot` documents filtered by the following criteria:

```
learning_language == doc.data().spoken_language
```

One approach here might be to use the [Array#filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to achieve this, where you would use the matching criteria above to filter user documents that match the required `learning_language`.

To acquire the filtered array of user documents as the resulting `ns_match` variable you will need to resolve an array of promises, seeing that you are executing the promise of `db.collection(ns_profile).doc(userSnapshot.id).get()` for each item in the `snapshot.docs` array.

You can use the [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) function to achieve this, as detailed in the comments below:

```
db.collection(ns_status)
.where("state", "==", "online")
.onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {

    /*
    Return the promise so that resolved ns_match array can be used externally
    */
    return Promise.all(snapshot.docs.map((userSnapshot) => {
        /* 
        For each document in docs, map each to a promise. Once all of
        these promises are resolved, Promise.all() will pass the array
        of documents to the next then() handler 
        */
        return db.collection(ns_profile).doc(userSnapshot.id).get();
    }))
    .then(users => {
        /*
        We now have a list of user documents in users. It seems like 
        the filter method is better suited to what you're wanting, so
        filter user documents based on the condition that
        spoken_language === learning_language
        */
        return users.filter(doc => {
            const spoken_language = doc.data().spoken_language;
            return learning_language === spoken_language;
        });
    })
    .then(ns_match => {
        /* 
        We now recieve the list of filtered user documents where the
        language ns_match applies for all items in ns_match
        */
        console.log(ns_match);

        /* Return this filtered array for use outside of this call */
        return ns_match;
    })
})
```

Hope that helps!